# Principle of virtual functions in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm new to C++ and I just learned about virtual functions.

I heard that compiler makes a vtable, which contains the class's virtual functions address, when I define a virtual function. When a virtual function is called, the compiler find its address using the vtable.

I can't really understand the reason why compiler didn't call the function of the class instance that the object belongs to.

Why is the compiler using a vtable? Could you explain this?

Comment: The reason to use a vtable is that when a derived class re-implements a virtual function, during the constructor of the derived class the vtable is updated to point to the derived implementation instead of the base.

Comment: Two words: *dynamic dispatch*.  Even though there are good explanations below, you need to at least hear the correct terminology.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I can't really understand the reason why compiler didn't call a function of class instance belong?

That's what the compiler does - makes sure that your program calls the function of the class to which the instance belongs. The key word here is *instance*: the knowledge of the instance's class is not available at compile time.

Consider this simple example:

```
struct Dude {
    virtual void howdy() = 0;
};
struct Bob : public Dude {
    virtual void howdy() { cout << "Hi, Bob!" << endl; }
};
struct Moe : public Dude {
    virtual void howdy() { cout << "Hi, Moe!" << endl; }
};
// Note the pass by reference below: passing by reference or by pointer,
// but not by value, is important for achieving polymorphic behavior.
void say_hi(Dude& dude) {
    dude.howdy(); // <<== Here is the tricky line
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Bob b;
    Moe m;
    Dude *d = rand() & 1 ? (Dude*)&b : &m;
    say_hi(*d);
}
```

Note the tricky line: the compiler has the instance, but it does not know the class. Actually, it kind of knows the class, but not the most specific one. The knowledge the compiler has at compile time is sufficient to know that there is a function called `howdy`, but not sufficient to decide which one of several possibilities would be the one to call at runtime.

This is where vtables come to the rescue: the compiler knows that subclasses of `Dude` will have a pointer to their `howdy` function embedded somewhere into their vtable. That's all they need to know at compile time! They insert a virtual call that looks up the function pointer at runtime, achieving the behavior that you expect (the fancy word for that kind of behavior is "polymorphism"). Here is a [demo of this program](http://ideone.com/NUjLoj) running on ideone.

Comment: Actually, `howdy` could be `const`, and you could be passing a `const` reference to `say_hi`... but I'm just nitpicking. :P

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Of course, that's what I'd do in a production problem. However, that's not essential to understanding basic principles of polymorphism, so I stripped the example to its bare minimum.

Comment: Your example is correct but maybe not ideal: I know of at least one compiler that will resolve the calls at compile time. The more classic `Base *p; if(rand() & 1) p = new Derived1; else p = new Derived2; p->do_something();` is slightly better because it avoids that "problem" and, in my opinion, is more illustrative anyways.

Comment: your adjustment doesn't actually avoid compile-time dispatch if inlining occurs, since each call site has just one possible dynamic type.